# OpenGL Renderer not working on Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Hi I'm building an Android game using OpenGL ES 1.0.  Everything was working fine until my Transformer tablet updated to Ice Cream Sandwich.  Now anything that uses OpenGL to render isn't showing up on screen.  I've been looking around and I've found the TextureView class. I'm not sure if I need to change all my GLSurfaceView and GLSurfaceView.Renderer code over to a TextureView class.  If this is the case are there any good tutorials out there on how to do the change over?  If anyone else has had this issue or knows how to resolve it I would really appreciate your help.

Update:
I've been messing around with emulators through eclipse and my app will run fine on an Android 4.0.3 tablet emulator but still won't work on the physical tablet.